# can .ptvs be saftely git ignored?

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I'm using visual studio 2013 and the python tools for visual studio.

While setting up the project i've begun adding to the standard VS .gitignore as it doesn't cover the tools.  I have a subdirectory labeled .ptvs in my environments folder.  Currently it only seems to have logs in it.

Is there any risk that something important ever ends up there?  Documentation is lacking in this area.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python Tools Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) seems to cache or generate files, logs and DB in the hidden folder `.ptvs`.
Since those data are generated, you should safely ignore that file and never version its content.

See for instance this discussion around the issue "[Visual Studio 2010 freezes with PTVS 2.0RC](http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/1929)":

> Are you using or can you upgrade to our latest dev build and see if the issue goes away?
>   **You may also want to try deleting the (hidden) `.ptvs` folder in your virtual environment and recreating the DB from scratch**.

Comment: I am using the latest dev version for visual studio.

Comment: @Highstead Excellent. I was only mentioning the "VS 2010" thread as an example of recommendation for `.ptvs` deletion.